# Using CASE in WHERE Statement when parameter has multiple values

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a problem which I think relates to having a multiple value parameter.

In my TblActivity there are two fields **`TblActivity.ActivityServActId`** and **`TblActivity.ActivityContractId`** which I want to include in my WHERE statement.

Filtering by these is optional.  If the user selects 'Yes' for the parameter `@YESNOActivity`, then I want to filter the query looking for rows where `TblActivity.ActivityServActId` matches one of the options in the parameter `@ServiceActivity`.

The same goes for the  `@YESNOContract`, `TblActivity.ActivityContractId` and `@Contract` respectively

I managed to get to this:

```
WHERE
(CASE WHEN @YESNOActivity = 'Yes' THEN TblActivity.ActivityServActId ELSE 0 END) 
IN (CASE WHEN @YESNOActivity = 'Yes' THEN @ServiceActivity ELSE 0 END)  

AND (CASE WHEN @YESNOContract = 'Yes' THEN TblActivity.ActivityContractId ELSE 0 END) 
IN (CASE WHEN @YESNOContract = 'Yes' THEN @Contract ELSE 0 END)
```

However, although this code works fine if there is only one value selected in the parameter `@ServiceActivity` or `@Contract`,  as soon as I have more than one value in these parameters, I get the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Query execution failed for dataset 'Activity'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I could understand it if I had an = instead of IN in the WHERE statement but can't figure this one out.

Using SQL Server 2008 and SSRS 2008-r2

Comment: I can guess, but you should explain how you storage multiple parameters in `@ServiceActivity`

Comment: Hi Juan, Thanks for tidying my question :)  @ServiceActivity is an integer, and I've ticked 'Allow multiple values'.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: You say when `@ServiceActivity` has one value works ok. So we need to know how you store multiple values in one Integer

Comment: I just use the standard settings for a multi value parameter in SSRS, which is to tick 'Allow multiple values'.  From what I can see, this turns it into a comma separated list.

Comment: Ok, then Philp already give the answer you need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `@ServiceActivity` is something like `1,2,3`

You can do something like this

```
WHERE  `,1,2,3,` LIKE `%,1,%`
```

So you format your variables

```
WHERE  ',' + @ServiceActivity + ',' LIKE '%,' + ID + ',%'
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5595)**

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT '1,2,3,4' as X UNION ALL
     SELECT '2,3,4,5' as X UNION ALL
     SELECT '3,4,5,6' as X UNION ALL
     SELECT '1,3,4,5' as X 
     ) as T
WHERE ',' + X + ','  LIKE  '%,1,%'
```

For Your Case

```
(CASE WHEN @YESNOActivity = 'Yes' 
           THEN ',' + @ServiceActivity + ','
           ELSE NULL 
 END)
LIKE
(CASE WHEN @YESNOActivity = 'Yes' 
           THEN '%,' + TblActivity.ActivityServActId + ',%'
           ELSE 0 
 END)
```

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Comment: ' (CASE WHEN (@YESNOActivity) = 'Yes' THEN (',' + TblActivity.ActivityServActId + ',')ELSE 0 END)

Comment: LIKE (CASE WHEN ATYESNOActivity = 'Yes' THEN (',' + ATServiceActivity + ',') ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Had to use AT instead of @ to get the code to post there.  Not sure why

Comment: I include a DEMO, let me know if that is enought for you understand.

Comment: I manage rewrite your code to fix that solution, try it and let me know

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, weekend got in the way.  I've tried the code above.  When I try running it with  param YESNOActivity = 'Yes' and one integer value in   param ServiceActivity I get the msg:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Comment: Also, When I try running it with multiple values where YESNOActivity = 'Yes' and several comma separated integers in  param ServiceActivity I get the msg:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%,' to data type int

Comment: USE convert instead `SELECT '%' + CONVERT(varchar(10), ServiceActivity) + '%' FROM table_name`

Comment: 'SELECT
  TblActivity.ActivityRefNo
  ,TblActivity.ActivityContractId
  ,TblActivity.ActivityServActId
  ,TblContract.ContractId
  ,TblContract.ContractName

FROM
  TblActivity
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TblContract
    ON TblActivity.ActivityContractId = TblContract.ContractId
  
WHERE
(CASE WHEN ATYESNOActivity = 'Yes' 
           THEN ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @ServiceActivity) + ','
           ELSE 0 
 END)
LIKE
(CASE WHEN ATYESNOActivity = 'Yes' 
           THEN '%,' + CONVERT(varchar(10), TblActivity.ActivityServActId) + ',%'
           ELSE 0 
 END) '

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where you suggest the convert goes - I've been playing about with it in the whereand the select part of the query, but can't get any combination to work.  Above is the last version of the code I have tried (with the @ symbols replaced as SO doesn't seem to like this symbol repeated in a comment!)

Comment: Sorry EileenS dont know what else I can do to help, I prepare a sqlFidlle with a demo and I wrote the code as I think your schema should be. You didnt say if you are getting error or something wrong. Why you dont try update the fiddle to match your db schema?

Comment: thanks Juan, although I haven't got this working yet I think this is along the right lines so voting this as the answer as most helpful in pointing towards the solution.  Philips link was useful too but can't vote twice!

Comment: @EileenS You can also leave an upvote if think the answer is helpfull. And I told you if you update the sqlFiddle I can take another look

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, the `IN` clause does not support parameters the way you are using them. The general syntax is

```
IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

you have

```
IN (@Param)
```

where something like 
   @Param = '1, 2, 3, 4'

Internally, SQL will turn this into

```
IN ('1, 2, 3, 4')
```

Note the quotes... you are now matching against a string!

There are a number of ways to address this. Search SO for "sql in clause parameter", pick one that works for you, and upvote it.

---

(Added)

[Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) seems pretty definitive on the subject. While long ago I upvoted the third reply (the one with table-value parameters), any of the high-vote answers could do the trick. The ideal answer depends on the overall problem you are working with. (I am not familiar with SSRS, and can't give more specific advice.)

Comment: I tought this was the issue, but in comment OP say is an integer.

Comment: I'm not sure what it means, but I think the "ticked 'Allow multiple values'" is something from the application side...?

Comment: Thanks, yes I can see that this is the problem.  I've had a search for 'SQL in clause parameter' and and struggling to find a solution I can understand (not SQL expert as you can prob tell).  Is there any one in particular you would recommend?

Comment: Added it as a link in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of messing around I put together a simple workaround for this by dropping my use of CASE altogether -  but I have a suspicion that this is not a terribly efficient way of doing things.

```
WHERE
(@YESNOActivity = 'No' OR (@YESNOActivity = 'Yes' AND
TblActivity.ActivityServActId IN (@ServiceActivity)))

AND

(@YESNOContract = 'No' OR (@YESNOContract = 'Yes' AND
TblActivity.ActivityContractId IN (@Contract)))
```